# Recognizing numbers (integers) in python using voice

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition

I am looking for code that can recognize a number by using a voice command. Is there any code on this? I would like to be able to recognize any number from 0 to 100.

I searched for a library and found [this](https://github.com/moebg/spoken-digit-recognition) one, but there is no documentation on how to use it.

The library that I am currently using is `speech_recognition` as you can see in the code below.

I am trying to write some code where the user can give any value of brightness (of screen) form 0 to 100 and program will change the brightness. I would like to learn how to do this over voice not with `int(input())`.

My code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import time
t = {'one':1,'two':2,'three':3,'four':4,'five':5,'six':6,'seven':7,'eight':8,'nine':9,'ten':10}
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('Speak anything: ')
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print('You said : {0} {1} '.format(text, t[text]))
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        print('Sorry could not recogonize your voice')
```

My brightness code:

```
brightness = amount # percentage [0-100]
c = wmi.WMI(namespace='wmi')
methods = c.WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods()[0]
methods.WmiSetBrightness(brightness, 0)
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the current code?

Comment: @AMC yes as current code only doing upto 10 . and i want upto 100 and in easy way. do you have any other method or suggestion .